# MVC Authentication not working in IIS (works in IIS Express)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2016

I have created an MVC project with individual authentication and am using the default template. When I launch the application from within visual studios (IIS express) I am able to view all the public pages, register an account, and login. Everything works great.

However, When I publish the project and host it on a full IIS server (on Windows Server 2016) I can view all the public pages, but registering or trying to sign in yields the following generic error:

[image]

I am using the LocalDb for the project and I noticed that the windows Identity on the deployed applicaiotn is "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" while the IIS Express application's is USER-DESKTOP\User. Is this error being caused by a permissions issue and if so how do you fix this?

Also, is it bad to use localDB for a deployed project? There will only be two users using the application and they are both trusted.

Comment: for me looks like error in ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable value, did you set it in IIS?

Comment: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to Development in the launhSettings.jason file of the project.... but I didn't set anything within IIS. I just did some light research but am still not 100% sure how to set them in IIS. Could you elaborate?

Comment: if there is web.config file in root of your hosted app you can add in aspNetCore  section env variable     <aspNetCore  stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>

Comment: if there is not this file you can just config via IIS Manager https://www.andrecarlucci.com/en/setting-environment-variables-for-asp-net-core-when-publishing-on-iis/

Answer (score 0):

It is totally not good idea to use localDB for a deployed project,
it is meant for developer testing only.

when you start debugging in vs the localDB is started.

its better if you use SQL Express
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866658

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your site application pool identity to the local system by following the below steps:

1)Open iis manager

2)Go to the application pool and select your application pool name.

3)Click on the advance setting.

4)There is a "Process Model" option, under which there is an "Identity" option. This is by default the application pool identity. Change it to Local System, and you're done.

[image]

Set “Load User Profile” to True.

[image]